# hanlde upload progress with saga and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

i am trying to make a progress bar in react.and after i upload file i get this error:
Error: call: argument of type {context, fn} has undefined or null `fn`

saga.js:

```
const identity = a => a;

const createAsync = file => {
  let emit;
  const chan = eventChannel(emitter => {
    emit = emitter;
    return () => {};
  });
  const promise = uploadVideoApi(file, function(e) {
    emit((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
  });

  return [promise, chan];
};

function* watchOnProgress(chan) {
  while (true) {
    const data = yield take(chan);
    yield put(uploadFileProgress(data));
  }
}

function* uploadVideo({ file }) {
  const [promise, chan] = createAsync(file);
  yield fork(watchOnProgress, chan);
  const result = yield call(identity(promise));
}
```

actions.js:

```
export function uploadFileProgress(percent) {
  return {
    type: UPLOAD_VIDEO_PROGRESS,
    percent,
  };
}
```

Comment: Where is `call` come from? if you meant to use `Function.prototype.call()` So you need to be aware it's a method you can run only on function instances, in this case, `identity.call(promise)`?
call docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: @DoriAviram its from redux-saga effects.source:https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/613

Comment: You can't use `call` on a promise. If you want to wait on a promise just do `yield promise`

Comment: Refer here : Might be duplicate issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402744/redux-saga-axios-and-progress-event